# What are columns in ls -la?

Tags: ls

I can't find what are columns when I use `ls -la`
For example:

```
-rw------- 1 myuser root 3272 may 14 16:30 my_file
```

`-rw------- 1` - access rights
`myuser` - owner of the file?
`root` - ?
`3272` - ?
`may 14 16:30` - date of modification?
`my_file` - name of file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order:

```
- type of the item 

        d   a directory.
        b   a block special file.
        c   a character special file.
        l   symbolic link.
        p   first-in, first-out (FIFO) pipe special file.
        s   local socket.
        -   ordinary file.

rw- permissions for user read, write, but no execution
--- permissions for group; none here
--- permissions for others; none here
1 is the amount of links (see `stat my_file`) 
myuser is the owner` 
root is the group
3272 is the size in bytes
may 14 16:30 last date changed
my_file is the filename
```

Regarding the `ls -la`: the `-l` shows a long list of files, the `a` shows hidden files if there are any (those start with a `.`) Omit the `a` if you want to use it for normal.

Comment: you missed `1` - it's the number of (hard) links to the file.

Comment: @raj nope was still editing but now I am done :+